# как в yii2 проверить главная ли страница?

Tags: php, yii2

как сделать проверку, главная ли страница сайта?
нужно реализовать функционал:
-если страница главная, то рендерим одну шапку, если другая страница то другую шапку

Comment: Учите английский - с ним вы получите доступ к англоязычным ресурсам SO ([ссылка на их ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341791/yii-check-if-homepage))

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно вот так

```
    if (Url::toRoute(Url::home()) == Url::toRoute(Yii::$app->controller->getRoute())) {

    // это главная страница.
}
```

Но как я понял вас. У вас вопрос стоит в том что бы отображать на главной хедер с одной разметкой, а на внутренних страницах с другой. То тогда как вариант можно подменять layout в action главной странице на другой отличный от общего

```
$this->layout = '@app/views/layouts/main';
```